# Generating migrations doesn't see my connection

Tags: migration, nestjs, typeorm

I made the connection to the database a separate module

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
            imports: [ConfigModule],
            inject: [ConfigService],
            useFactory: configService => ({
                type: configService.get('DATABASE_TYPE'),
                host: configService.get('DATABASE_HOST'),
                port: configService.get('DATABASE_PORT'),
                username: configService.get('DATABASE_USERNAME'),
                password: configService.get('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
                database: configService.get('DATABASE_NAME'),
                entities: ['./dist/**/*.entity.{js,ts}'],
                synchronize: false,
                migrationsRun: true,
                logging: true,
                migrations: ['./dist/modules/database/migration/*.{js,ts}'],
                cli: {
                    migrationsDir: 'src/modules/database/migration',
                },
            }),
        }),
    ],
})
export class DatabaseModule {}
```

This works fine in a docker container. But when I want to run the creation of the migration, I get the error

```
Error: No connection options were found in any orm configuration files.
    at ConnectionOptionsReader.<anonymous> (/Users/user1/Documents/app/src/connection/ConnectionOptionsReader.ts:43:19)
```

My commands for working with migrations

```
        "migration:generate": "ts-node node_modules/.bin/typeorm migration:generate -n",
        "migration:run": "ts-node node_modules/.bin/typeorm migration:run",
        "migration:revert": "ts-node node_modules/.bin/typeorm migration:revert"
```

In the command, I did not specify the connection konyig and as I understood orm cannot find my config for the connection, how can I tell it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem is that the CLI of TypeORM doesn't know that in your Nest application you use a `TypeormModule` to configure the connection. The CLI expects the config in the one of the following formats described in the [documentation](https://typeorm.io/#/using-ormconfig).

So the easiest way to fix your problem would be to create a file called `ormconfig.js` and set your connection config here. Like so:

```
module.exports = {
  "type": "mysql",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 3306,
  "username": "test",
  "password": "test",
  "database": "test"
}
```

Assuming that your `configService` reads the values from the environmental variables, you could also do:

```
module.exports = {
  "type": "mysql",
  "host": process.env.DB_HOST,
  "port": process.env.DB_PORT,
  "username": process.env.DB_USERNAME,
  "password": process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  "database": process.env.DB_DATABASE
}
```

So that the config is the same as the one in the app.